# Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies , SPLIT_BUNDLE 4: Data sent off device undeclared in Data safety form

Tags: android

Issue found: Invalid Data safety section
We reviewed your app's Data safety section in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety section that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is a requirement even if your app does not collect any user data.

We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app's Data safety section as user data collected.

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 4: Data sent off device undeclared in Data safety form: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID)

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: What i need to fill in Data safety form ?